# Twilio invalid StatusCallback URL using python and flask

Tags: python, flask, twilio, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to send an sms message to the caller in Twilio using a python and flask webhook.  My python webhook is hosted on pythonanywhere.com.

A snippet of the code is shown below.  I haven't been able to find any details on the internet on why I keep getting an invalid StatusCallback URL error.  All of the other routes seem to work fine.

```
def twiml(resp: VoiceResponse) -> flask.Response:
    resp = flask.Response(resp)
    resp.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml'
    return resp


@app.route('/send-message', methods=['POST'])
def send_message():
    response = VoiceResponse()

    msg = 'a text message'

    response.sms(msg,
                 status_callback=url_for('sms_callback', source=request.endpoint),
                 status_callback_method='POST',
                 to=request.values.get('From'),
                 from_=request.values.get('To')
                 )

    return twiml(response)


@app.route('/sms-callback', methods=['POST'])
def sms_callback():
    response = VoiceResponse()

    response.say('message callback')

    return twiml(response)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course I found out the answer after I post the question.  Hopefully this helps someone else!

The `status_callback` parameter must be the **full** URL link and not just the relative link, since it is being passed to the Twilio servers. They don't know how to handle the relative link, so it's invalid.

I passed the full link as shown below and it works.

```
    response.sms(msg,
             status_callback='https://myaccount.pythonanywhere.com/sms-callback',
             status_callback_method='POST',
             to=request.values.get('From'),
             from_=request.values.get('To')
             )
```